# Transferring data from cygwin executable[C] to managed program[managed C++]?

Tags: c, cygwin, ipc

I have a program running on cygwin that generates some data that puts it in a buffer, I want the managed code to copy that data from the buffer. what's the best way to do so?

The library I am using builds only on cygwin so I can not compile on native windows hence the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could host a CLR inside your cygwin C process, and send it the data, but I guess (from your 'ipc' tag) that you want to keep the two processes separate. You can read more about hosting the CLR [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx).

So you'll need to resort to some sort of interprocess communications method. You could use a [Named Pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this - it'll be a lot easier than opening sockets.

You can also try using [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). It's usually used for high performance communications, but it's simple enough that it might make sense for you as well.

Comment: I am open to hosting CLR, but I din't know it was possible.

Comment: Added a link for Microsoft's hosting documentation.